# Sufficient condition for $M$ to have constant curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

*I decided to keep my original question. However, I'm having trouble only in a part of it (check **NOTE**)*

Let's consider a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, with the Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$.
I would like to know why is it that if $M$ has constant sectional curvature, then $\nabla R=0$, where $R$ is the curvature tensor.

Moreover, I read that $\nabla R=0$ does not imply that necessarily that $M$ has constant curvature. However, if $\dim(M)=2$, that holds. (*I read in an online set of exercises*)

Can anyone give solution/hints/references for this questions ?
Thanks in advance...

**NOTE :** Meanwhile, I figured it out how to prove that if $M$ has constant sectional curvature, then$\nabla R=0$. However, it is not clear to me the second question : If $\dim(M)=2$ and $M$ is such that $\nabla R=0$, then $M$ has constant curvature. How ?

Answer (score 4):

If $(M,g)$ has constant sectional curvature, its curvature tensor $R$ can be built up from a constant function, the metric $g$ and a Kronecker-$\delta$ by tensorial operations, see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_decomposition . Since all these ingredients are parallel, so is $R$. 
In general $\nabla R=0$ is equivalent to $(M,g)$ being a locally symmetric space, and there are many examples of such spaces which do not have constant curvature, for example Grassmannians. 
In dimension $2$, the Riemann curvature can be built up from the Gauss curvature, the metric and a Kronecker-$\delta$ by tensorial operations. If you look at the explicit form for this, you see that $\nabla R=0$ if and only if the Gauss curvature is constant.

Comment: Do you have any good reference for the (explicit) relation between Gauss curvature and Riemann curvature in $\dim(M)=2$ case ? Also, do you know a way I can conclude $\nabla R=0$ - assuming $(M,g)$ has constant sectional curvature - without using that Ricci decomposition? Anyway, thank you for the answer Andreas :)

Comment: Check my NOTE in my question, Andreas. Thanks for the attention :)

Comment: An alternative way to see that in dimension 2 constant curvature is equivalent to $\nabla R=0$ is to observe that the latter is always equivalent to $(M,g)$ being locally symmetric. In dimension 2 one verifies that $S^2$, $R^2$ and $H^2$ are symmetric spaces by exhibiting explicit symmetries about each point (order 2 rotations).

Comment: A link for the dimension two case is in Yuri Vyatkin's comment to your original question. For the second part, I think it should be possible to directly conclude the form of the curvature tensor (as in Yuri's comment with constant $K$) from the fact that sectional curvature is constant. (I can imagine how to try doing this, but haven't tried.)